# Rails helper method is called when I do not want to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build a 4-choice quiz application using Ruby on Rails and JavaScript.
If you click one of the Choice Buttons at the Question View, a helper method "updateData(bool)" updates database and then you'll see the result without view transition. And if you click the Chart Button after answering, the view transitions to the Chart View.

However, the helper method "updateData" seems to be called not only by Choice Button but by Chart Button. It updates the database and increment the Question Number against my expectation.
According to the outputs from console.log, it is not likely that the Chart Button calls JavaScript function sendAnswer(ans).

I use Rails 5.0.1.
I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function sendAnswer(ans){
      var questionID = getNumber();
      var data = readCSV(questionID);
      // True if answer number matches correct answer number
      if(data[5] == ans ){
        console.log("true")
        <% updateData(1) %>
      }else{
        console.log("false")
        <% updateData(0) %>
      };
      // Create Chart Button after answering
      $("#bottom").append('<div id="showChart"></div>');
      $("#showChart").html('<button id="showChartBtn" onclick="showChart()">Show Chart</button>');
    };
  </script>

  <script>
    function showChart(){
      window.location.href = "/chart";
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <% alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D"] %>
  <!-- For loop to make A-D choices -->
  <% for i in 0..3 %>
    <button class="choice_btn" id="btn_<%= i %>" onclick="sendAnswer(<%= i %>);">
      <%= alphabets[i] %>
    </button>
  <% end %>
 <div id="bottom">
  <!-- Chart Button comes here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

```
# Return user according to remember token
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end

# Increment the Question Number, and increment the Correct Answer Number if true
def updateData(bool)
  current_user.questionNum += 1
  current_user.correctNum += bool
  current_user.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html code above, embedded Ruby <% updateData %> is executed while generating HTML.

I should instead call Controller Action by Button Click Event, and then call helper method via Action.